# How to log android phone properties?

Tags: android, logging, mobile

I want to log everything for user experiment. But also I want to log android phone device id , which phone brand , what is app version ... something like this.

Firebase Analythics and Appsee are doing like this. Where I start ?

EDIT:

Think about I will write a SDK and with this SDK can learn everything.

Comment: There are many option for crash log 
1) Firebase Analythics 2) Fabric

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getDeviceName () {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith (manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize (model);
    }
    else {
        return capitalize (manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}

public static int getAppVersion () {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = MainApplication.getContext ().getPackageManager ()
                .getPackageInfo (MainApplication.getContext ().getPackageName (), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException ("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the example to get device properties code

```
public static String getAPIlevel() {
    return "Android API :" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
}

public static String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return SubUtils.capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return SubUtils.capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}

public static String getDeviceVersion(Context activity) {
    String v;
    try {
        v = activity.getApplication().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        return v.replace("-staging", "");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
public static String getUDID(Context activity) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
        String tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        String androidId = "" + Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());

        return deviceUuid.toString();
    } else {
        return Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
}
```

### OR

you can use [AndroidCodeUtils](https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode) for more complete devices access infomation

Comment: don't pass activity context, it may cause a leak, or sometimes break the functionality (if activity instance can't give context, in the case of finishing or destroy )